# How come I can't decrypted my AES encrypted message on someone elses AES decryptor?

Tags: python, aes, pycrypto

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import os

key = 'mysecretpassword'
iv = os.urandom(16)
plaintext1 = 'Secret Message A'
encobj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
ciphertext1 = encobj.encrypt(plaintext1) 
encryptedText = ciphertext1.encode('base64')
print encryptedText
decobj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
print decobj.decrypt(ciphertext1)
```

I copied the printed value of `encryptedText` and the `key` from my code and pasted to the websites below.

http://www.everpassword.com/aes-encryptor

http://www.nakov.com/blog/2011/12/26/online-aes-encryptor-decryptor-javascript/

I would expected it to be able to decrypt my cipher, but it doesn't. Thus I must be using pycrypto wrong. How do I fix this? The two sites can both encrypt and decrypt between each other, but mines can't. Both the websites do indeed use CBC mode.

Comment: Did you try different modes? I cannot see whether the site uses XTS, CBC or maybe only ECB. Try different modes. Note that you use an IV but the site does not ask for one.

Comment: You need to give the decrypter the IV.  That website doesn't accept an IV.  So it is probably using ECB, not CBC.

Comment: Also, how do you know that website takes the ciphertext as base64?

Comment: Yes, I made the wrong assumption that the website takes the ciphertext as base64.

Comment: Actually, my assumption is correct the website does take the ciphertext as base64. It even explicitly says in the second web link. There's no way it can be in ascii or something else. So I am still confused with what I'm doing wrong in the code. How do I get it to be decrypted by the websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the page source for the website in question, you will see that it uses [gibberish-aes](https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes) javascript library. To see whet you have to do to make it work, you have to study what it does.

Looking through its [source code](https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes/blob/ba17eb3cec5c4bd41a8d52c98421cee4b99b3d48/src/gibberish-aes.js), it seems to use a random salt for encryption. That, prepended by the string `Salted__` forms the beginning of the cyphertext before it is base64 encoded.

```
randArr = function(num) {
    var result = [], i;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        result = result.concat(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
    }
    return result;
},
```

and

```
enc = function(string, pass, binary) {
        // string, password in plaintext
        var salt = randArr(8),
        pbe = openSSLKey(s2a(pass, binary), salt),
        key = pbe.key,
        iv = pbe.iv,
        cipherBlocks,
        saltBlock = [[83, 97, 108, 116, 101, 100, 95, 95].concat(salt)];
        string = s2a(string, binary);
        cipherBlocks = rawEncrypt(string, key, iv);
        // Spells out 'Salted__'
        cipherBlocks = saltBlock.concat(cipherBlocks);
        return Base64.encode(cipherBlocks);
    },
```

For decryption, it uses picks the random portion of the salt out of the beginning of the cyphertext after base64 decoding (the first `slice` operator):

```
dec = function(string, pass, binary) {
    // string, password in plaintext
    var cryptArr = Base64.decode(string),
    salt = cryptArr.slice(8, 16),
    pbe = openSSLKey(s2a(pass, binary), salt),
    key = pbe.key,
    iv = pbe.iv;
    cryptArr = cryptArr.slice(16, cryptArr.length);
    // Take off the Salted__ffeeddcc
    string = rawDecrypt(cryptArr, key, iv, binary);
    return string;
},
```

The missing piece now is the `openSSLkey` function:

```
openSSLKey = function(passwordArr, saltArr) {
    // Number of rounds depends on the size of the AES in use
    // 3 rounds for 256
    // 2 rounds for the key, 1 for the IV
    // 2 rounds for 128
    // 1 round for the key, 1 round for the IV
    // 3 rounds for 192 since it's not evenly divided by 128 bits
    var rounds = Nr >= 12 ? 3: 2,
    key = [],
    iv = [],
    md5_hash = [],
    result = [],
    data00 = passwordArr.concat(saltArr),
    i;
    md5_hash[0] = GibberishAES.Hash.MD5(data00);
    result = md5_hash[0];
    for (i = 1; i < rounds; i++) {
        md5_hash[i] = GibberishAES.Hash.MD5(md5_hash[i - 1].concat(data00));
        result = result.concat(md5_hash[i]);
    }
    key = result.slice(0, 4 * Nk);
    iv = result.slice(4 * Nk, 4 * Nk + 16);
    return {
        key: key,
        iv: iv
    };
},
```

So basically you have to translate the `openSSLKey` function to Python and feed it your password and salt. That creates a (key, iv) tuple. Use those to encrypt your data. Prepend the string `Salted__` and the salt to the ciphertext before encoding it with base64. Then it should work, I think.